# How to improve Clojures error messages

Tags: clojure

I've been playing a bit with Clojure and so far is fairly impressed, but one thing that I keep running into is wierd error messages from Clojure. This comes in two forms: Java errors, like null pointer exceptions and in clojure syntax errors, like missing parenthesis pair. I was wondering if anyone know of a way to get better error messages?

Part of it is of course from learning a new language, but improving the error messages can never hurt :)

Comment: You should use an editor that auto-balances parens (e.g. Emacs + paredit).  Missing parens aren't something you should ever encounter when writing Lisp in my opinion.

Comment: I second Brian's comment. My favorite environment is currently the IDEA IDE with its La Clojure plugin. But for simple stuff, Waterfront works too. You can set that up so it auto-evaluates your entire workspace whenever you edit your text.

Comment: I use Emacs of course but the problem is when you forgot a pair of paranthesis. Like a for [BLA] do <MISSING () pair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the compiler and other stuff are being developed by a fairly small band of people led by Rich Hickey, and if you're a competent programmer then it's conceivable you could contribute to the compiler's development.

Clojure headquarters is at: http://clojure.org

You can get information and documentation there, and access to the source code and git repository...

...and there's a Google Group for it: http://groups.google.com/group/clojure?pli=1

Take a look and offer your help, if you dare. Good luck and power to you!

Comment: Yes the lack of good error messages is certainly something that should be taken up by the community.

Comment: Yeah maybe simply reporting bugs for some cases would be a good start :-)

Answer (score 1):

This might help: http://github.com/mmcgrana/clj-stacktrace.

You can use it on the REPL to get more useful stack traces.  It's still not great, but definitely better than nothing.